# Angular ng-style to alternate table colours

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to create a table. I have an ng-style filter that looks at the values in a table row and if a certain word appears it changes that colour of that row.

The expression that I'm using is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in b" ng-style="a.name == 'user1'?{'background-color':'orange'}:{}">
```

This is working fine, however what I would like to be able to do is alternate between orange and another colour when there are more than two rows that match so that I don't just have solid blocks of colour in my table.

Is it possible to add another condition to ng-style that looks at if a row is odd or even and then I can alternate the colours of matching rows that way? Or is there another way to do this using css? I'm not sure if I can control css from ng-style?

Comment: Check out the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat.  You do get $even and $odd properties.  Best!

Comment: You can actually apply ng-class with the same logic. and then use css to alternate colors http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_odd_even That way I believe you can keep your code and style separate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it in angular without css for example like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in b" ng-style="{'background-color': (a.name == 'user1') ? ($index % 2 === 0 ? 'orange' : 'red') : 'auto'}">
```

but css also has even and odd pseudo classe which could be used here..

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the type of thing that I was looking for, however that expression does not work for me.

Comment: I just got it working  by removing the :{} at the end! Thanks!

Comment: ups yeah that was a typo sorry :P

Comment: @PatrickKelleter, I tried in similar lines. Does this solution address "then I can alternate the colours of matching rows that way" of OP? aren't we checking that a row is even or not instead of checking that a matching row is even or not?? Beautiful solution indeed.

Comment: yes, indeed it alters about the absolute even/odd characteristics of the row, not only of the relative (matched) rows. however, the wanted solution of OP was meant to avoid two highlighted rows of the same color besides each other. the given code solves this issue. for only counting highlighted rows we would have to add some more code, idealy into the controller (having a own counting variable instead of $index etc)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nagasandeepbondili/ty9w93rh/ This is what I was referring to.  We may actually need to take counting variable as you suggested but that's not necessary to OP it seems. Cheers @PatrickKelleter :)